# Git failed with a fatal error. Failed to write item to store

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019

When trying to clone GIT repo, getting below error from Visual Studio

> Git failed with a fatal error. 
> Failed to write item to store. [0x520]
> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been 
> terminated 
> POST git-upload-pack (214 bytes) 
> remote: Azure Repos
>
> remote: remote: 
> Found 3 objects to send (17ms)

Tried in both the versions of Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.7 and 16.8.

16.7: Tried to clone multiple times, sometimes all the files gets downloaded but above error still pops up.

16.8: No download or cloning happening, same error.

I tried recreating Azure personal access token, also added an Generic Credentials into Windows Credentials.

Nothing worked, any help here, please.

Using:
Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 & Git-2.29.2.2-64-bit

Comment: I have the exact same issue - does not accept my credentials but signs in, can browse remote branches, etc... but not get latest on any or push any changes.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message in VS 2019 with git 2.29.2 as well. Oddly though, my git actions do complete before getting the error. I've tried removing my credentials from the credential manager and reinstalling git. No luck so far.

Comment: I raised a ticket with Microsoft Technical support, they suggested to check Azure DevOps setup for the account and seems not VS issue. As a workaround, Git commands are working.

Comment: If we clone the repo from browser using option "Clone button" and select IDE as "Clone in 
Visual Studio", the repo download will be successful. So it seems browser authenticates the VS IDE to download the repo. But, if we try to clone directly from VS, the Git authentication window pops up.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Processes running with elevated privileges are locked out of the Git Credential Manager store, but processes running normally have no problem. (my company is using a privilege manager to provide fine-grained admin rights to specific processes while denying them to other processes - I think this is related to the problem)

Comment: @Zarepheth, Yes I feel the same. Somehow organization security permissions overriding GIT manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It worked perfectly fine outside Visual Studio 2022, eg in a cmd window and even in Visual Studio Code. My solution was to change the [credential store](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md).

```
git config credential.credentialStore dpapi
```